# Why is cell bounds and frame size incorrect when UITableView is in UIPopoverController?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I have a UIViewController subclass with XIB which is 320 wide and 400 high. The XIB has a UITableView which fills the width and height of the view.

In the viewDidLoad method of the VC, I have the following

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(600.0, 400.0);
```

The tableview is displaying correctly in the popover. All good so far.

Now I'm programatically adding a UIProgressView to the tableview cells but there's something I don't understand. In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I wanted to set the width of the UIProgressView in relation to the cell's width, yet the cell.frame.size.width and cell.bounds.size.width are the original 320 and **not** the actual 600 as displayed.

I can workaround it by using the tableview's width value but I'm confused why the values aren't correct at the cell level.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the size values are as expected in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

So I'm guessing between `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `willDisplayCell` is where the resizing to popover happens.